# On C and generic functions

Tags: c, generics

I'd like to implement search using C generics

```
int lsearchGeneric(void *key, void *base, int n, int elemSize)
{
    int i =0;

    for(; i < n; i++)   {
        void *elemAddr = (char*) base + i * elemSize;           
        if(memcmp(key, elemAddr , elemSize) == 0) {
            return i;
        }
    }

    return -1;
}
```

This function is called with

```
char *key = strdup("w");
char *base = strdup("two");

int result = lsearchGeneric (&key, base, 3, sizeof(char));
printf("Position: %d\n", result); // prints -1
```

I wonder what am i missing here. Instead of -1, i would expect 1, as "w" is the second letter in "two"

For those (you know who you are) who wonder whether this is homework - the answer is "no it is not. I am following Programming paradigms lecture from iTunesU"

Comment: Have you tried stepping through the program in a debugger?  Given that you're doing this for learning, you'll learn rather more from doing that than from the answer here....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like you have an extra `&` in your function call:

```
int result = lsearchGeneric (&key, base, 3, sizeof(char));
                             ^
                        does not belong here!
```

You're passing the address of the pointer rather than the pointer itself. The giveaway here is that you weren't consistent with the two operands: You passed `&key` and `base`, one with and the other without the `&`.

**Small Note:**

This "generic" might not work properly with [structs that have padding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_structure_alignment#Data_structure_padding). As the padding values are unspecified and may be different with otherwise identical structs.

Comment: You posted this the moment i thought of it too :) Thank you

Comment: Actually, your comment about compiler warnings is erroneous, because the function takes a ``void*``.  (And it's perfectly valid to cast a ``char**`` to a ``void*``, so this is all technically legal code.)  That's why using "generics" like this in C is dangerous!

Comment: @BrooksMoses You're correct, I though the function parameter was `char*` instead of `void*`... fixing...

Answer (score 2):

If you step through this in a debugger, the first thing you'll notice is that the value of "key" inside the function isn't "w" -- instead, it's some garbage.  If you look closer, you'll notice that the address isn't the same as when you checked it out in the main program, either.

The reason for this is that you are calling your function with the address of the pointer of the key value -- `&key` -- rather than the address of the key value itself, which is `key`.  Remove the extraneous `&`, and it works right.

Comment: +1 for correcting my mistake and pointing at using a debugger.